# Notice: Undefined index: on session variables possible to ignore?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, warnings, undefined-index

Backstory

I used to host my website on a GoDaddy dedicated server. Typically I would (on successful user login) apply something to a `_SESSION` variable to determine a user was successfully logged in like

```
if ($_SESSION['user_logged_in'] == true) {
    // did stuff here
}
```

I would typically apply something like this to the top of a page so in case the user was not logged in it would redirect them somewhere else, like...

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['user_logged_in'] != true) {
    // direct them to log in
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/login");
    die();
} else {
    // user is logged in so show them stuff
}
?>
```

I am moving from GoDaddy to AWS and have built my own EC2 instance with Apache and so on. Now when I am accessing pages when a user is not logged in I am getting errors like

```
Notice: Undefined index: user_logged_in in /var/www/html/index.php on line X
```

I understand why I am receiving this message since technically since the user is not logged in and the session variable has not been created.

but....

My first question is, is there a setting in apache that ignores whether a session variable has been set to not display the error? I never got this message when I was with GoDaddy so I am assuming so.

Second, what is the security risks involved in not using something like `if (isset($_SESSION['variable'])` to determine whether a session variable exists or not?

Wouldn't using something like `if ($_SESSION['user_logged_in'] != true) {` be the same thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`error_reporting`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to turn off `Notice` level errors:

```
error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE);
```

but in the long run it's better to fix the code using something like the Null Coalescing operator [`??`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) e.g.

```
if (($_SESSION['user_logged_in'] ?? false) != true) {
```

Comment: But, if any, are there any security risks involved in simply ignoring these errors?

Comment: @CesarBielich the issue is that if you compare an undefined variable to be not strictly equal to `false` (e.g. `$_SESSION['user_logged_in'] !== false`) it will pass, which might cause your code to think that someone was logged in, which would be a security problem. As long as you don't use that style of programming you should be ok. https://3v4l.org/FT8SR